# Convert string to Guid using SHA256 without truncating

Tags: c#, hash, guid, sha256, sha

Is there a way to convert a string to a GUID using SHA256 without truncating the 16 bytes?

Currently I have this:

```
using SHA256 sha2 = SHA256.Create())
{
     var hash = sha2.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(string));
     return new Guid(hash.Take(16).ToArray());
}
```

Comment: A Guid *is* 16 bytes long. So how would you fit the rest?

Comment: The SHA-256 algorithm creates a 32 byte hash. A `Guid` is 16 bytes. You cannot put 32 bytes into a 16 byte data structure. You could convert it to two guids.

Comment: Why? A `Guid` is 16 bytes. It's not like you're seeding it and making a new one. The `Guid` string constructor is literally taking a `Guid` represented in a different format and creating an instance of the `Guid` class.

Comment: @HansKesting Or is there another data type similar to Guid that takes 32 bytes?

Comment: @JasonBoyd Or is there another data type similar to Guid that takes 32 bytes?

Comment: @DeVonte Why not just return the byte array that `ComputeHash` creates? What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: @DeVonte a Guid and a Hash are 2 entirely different things. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @JasonBoyd Ultimately, I wanted to use SHA2 to hash the string and return as Guid so I can save in database as a uniqueidentifier.

Comment: @McAden Ultimately, I wanted to use SHA2 to hash the string and return as Guid so I can save in database as a uniqueidentifier

Comment: I wanted a more secure way of hashing my string instead of using MD5 I wanted to use SHA2. I know that MD5 returns 16 bytes exactly.

Answer (score 0):

A hash is not the same as a Guid. Trying to equate the 2 is incorrect.

If you want a unique identifier:

```
return Guid.NewGuid();
```

That'll give you one.

If you want the hash, store is as bytes or a string, not a `Guid`

Comment: Thank you I just wanted to see if it was possible or not